# which authentication token should i use?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

i have been coding a jwt mechanism and i need to set the security context for the spring security when i analyze other code from net i see that most of the code uses UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken but in my case there is just a simple id and some credential so which token should i use? i found [that](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) and when i research each token, there is no explanation for the usage.

Also if i use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken with empty password field. Is it okay?

Comment: See [JwtAuthenticationToken](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtAuthenticationToken.html). Also see `JwtAuthenticationConverter` that converts `Jwt` to `JwtAuthenticationToken`.

Comment: I have created my token by io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts and it returns String but JwtAuthenticationToken takes Jwt how can i convert it? @Ritesh

Comment: You can use [Jwt.Builder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/Jwt.Builder.html) to convert `io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts` to [Jwt](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/Jwt.html).